# Cannot get data from XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get some data from a web page with HtmlAgilityPack which gets some variables and gives some results.
I want to retrieve 3 data fields from this webpage and so far I can only get the 2 of them.
My code so far

```
            struct Result
            {
                public string Description;
                public string thirdCountryDuty;
                public string tarifPreference;
            }

        private Result LoadWebPage(string url, string taric)
        {
         //This is the webpage which contains all three datas that I want. I just write it here as 
         url for testing
url = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&SimDate=20200503&Area=SG&MeasType=&StartPub=&EndPub=&MeasText=&GoodsText=&op=&Taric=6213900010&search_text=goods&textSearch=&LangDescr=el&OrderNum=&Regulation=&measStartDat=&measEndDat=%22;"

            var result = new Result();
            taric = "6213900010";//This is a variable. I give it here for testing purposes
            txtEditCountry.Text = "SG";//This is a variable. I give it here for testing purposes
            try
            {

                var web2 = new HtmlWeb();
                var doc2 = web2.LoadFromBrowser(url, html =>
                {
                    // WAIT until the dynamic text is set
                    return !html.Contains("<div id=\"" + taric.ToString() + "\"></div>");
                });
               //t1 is the data that I cannot get
               var t1 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(text(),'" + txtEditCountry.Text + "')] and .//span[contains(.,'duty_rate')]]").InnerText; 
                //This is working
                var t2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@id,'"+ taric + "')]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]").InnerText;
                 //This is working
                 var t3 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class,'duty_rate')]").InnerText;


                Console.WriteLine("Text 1: " + t1);
                Console.WriteLine("Text 2: " + t2);
                Console.WriteLine("Text 3: " + t3);
                result = new Result
                {
                    Description = t2,
                    thirdCountryDuty = t3,
                    tarifPreference = t1
                };

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                result.Description= null;
                result.thirdCountryDuty = null;
                result.tarifPreference = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Check your data and try again \n" + ex.ToString());
                return result;
            }
        }
```

The data that I cannot get is t1 as I wrote in the code. This field is visible when I put a specific country in url "&Area=country code". If I put another country it will give me another number or 0%. If I don't put anything it will give me a list with all countries.
If I use this as Xpath

```
var t1 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(text(),'" + txtEditXora.Text + "')]").InnerText;
```

It returns the country correct for example

> Singapore (SG)

I want the tarif Preference percentage for this country

This is the first time that I use XPath and I am still learning but I wan't this for my project.

[image: Xpath and html]

Comment: looks like the data is inside a <td>

`$x("//span[contains(text(),'SG')] and .//td[contains(.,'duty')]")`

Comment: @Saravanan I tried but it doesn't work. It throws System.XML.XPath.XPathException. You have a little error. The code should be //span[contains(text(),'SG') and //td[contains(.,'duty')]] but still doesn't return data

Comment: it returns true, meaning that the conditions `anded` have succeeded. if you want to select, use a selector in the hierarchy

Comment: @Saravanan based on your comment I tried //span[contains(text(),'SG') and //*[(@class='duty_rate')]] but it returns the name of the country and not the 8.30% that is in the  <span class="duty_rate">8.30 %</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I don't have time to check if it would work with other countries.

```
doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='" + taric + "']//td[@name='measure_description_search']//td")[4].InnerText
```

Or this:

```
doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='" + taric + "']//span[@class='duty_rate']")[1].InnerText
```

Comment: Both seems to working. I will test them with different codes and different countries and I will update my question. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I tested them uslng the same framework and same web page, and made sure they both work.

Comment: The second one fetch the correct result at least for the ones I tested. I believe it will work with all of them. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
//text()[contains(.,"preference")]/../../td[2]
```

Comment: This returns the first "duty_rate" which in the specific variables is 10.00%. Can I select the second value somehow?

Comment: I guess that is because there is more than one use of ```duty_rate``` as a class., Perhaps try ```//div[@id="measure_3712467"]//span[@class="duty_rate"]```. It's hard to answer the question without having the website and understanding how it's put together.

Comment: this works but my problem with this is that the "measure_3712467" is something that I don't have it as variable. It changes without knowing it and it is different in every code

Comment: I thought that would be the case :\ could you send the link to the website?

Comment: <https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&SimDate=20200503&Area=SG&MeasType=&StartPub=&EndPub=&MeasText=&GoodsText=&op=&Taric=6213900010&search_text=goods&textSearch=&LangDescr=el&OrderNum=&Regulation=&measStartDat=&measEndDat=> The part that says Taric="number" changes acording with the variable, also the Area="country" changes. In the specific url it has two duty_rate. The first I retrieve it already, I want the second one

Comment: Then `//text()[contains(.,"preference")]/following::span[@class="duty_rate"][1]` should be the way to go.

Comment: @Pete I will check it later. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Pete Sorry but this doesn't work in my case. Thanks for your time. Oguz Ozgul working fine for me.